# What's "straggling figure"?

Tags: meaning

I’d like to ask about the sentence from Lion’s Mane by Conan Doyle.

> There was no mistaking that tall, angular, ***straggling*** figure. It was
>   Ian Murdoch, the mathematician.

Can someone tell me what to picture in my head when I see the word “straggling” used as in the sentence above, that is, for an adjective to describe someone?  This is even the first time that I encountered this word, but used to mean the way someone looks?
My dictionary gives the example “straggling village” which means “scattered, sparsely populated village”(?) but doesn’t put anything about it being used for people. But it says in definition that “straggling” means something like “fraying”, so maybe this Ian Murdoch’s outfit is loose and not sharp-looking? Or is this about his body itself, the way he walks even?  I don’t know. I can’t picture anything.  Could someone tell me? Thanks.

Comment: It is indeed an odd word to use of a person. I would picture a straggling village as consisting of houses spread thinly along a road rather than grouped in a compact way, so I imagine Mr Murdoch as being thin and loose-limbed (we're told that he is tall).

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/straggle) has '**straggle**: an untidy or irregularly arranged _mass_ or group'. The verb usually means to move as an untidy group, but the participle is used to refer to the nounal sense.

Comment: A *straggler* is a term used in statistics for outlying data, although I can't find a good link to make an answer. Perhaps ACD chose that word to further describe his mathematician.